# Stop “Position iPhone camera” appearing on my phone

Tags: iphone, appletv, facetime

I attempted to use an iPhone with an Apple TV FaceTime app. It didn’t work correctly, and now the iPhone constantly shows this message pasted below. No amount of pressing “Disconnect” or “skip this step” stops it from happening.

I can’t see any way to remove the phone from the AppleTV’s settings.

How do I stop it appearing?

[image: screenshot from phone]

Comment: And if you reboot the phone?